# How to add value for each points with style line?

Tags: linux, gnuplot

I use this script Gnuplot :

```
set title "df -m command test"
set terminal png truecolor size 720,480 background rgb "#eff1f0"
set output "/xxx/xxx/xxx/test.png"
set grid
set style line 1 \
    linecolor rgb '#0060ad' \
    linetype 1 linewidth 2 \
    pointtype 7 pointsize 1.5
set offsets 0.5,0.5,0,0.5
set datafile separator ","
set ylabel " MB BLOCK "
set xlabel " Date "
set format y "%g"
plot "/xxxx/xxx/xxx/TEST.txt" using 2:xtic(1) with linespoints linestyle 1 title "MB used"
```

With these data :

```
2019-08-28,384.00
2019-08-29,394.00
2019-08-30,354.00
2019-08-31,384.00
2019-09-01,484.00
2019-09-02,324.00
2019-09-03,384.00
```

To create this graph :
[image: image_2]
<sub>(source: [noelshack.com](https://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2019/35/5/1567168668-test.png))</sub>

Can you show me how I can put the value over each point ?

Comment: it seems my answer below solved your problem, since you are already using it for your next question. So, then please mark the answer as acceptable and solved. That's the way SO works.

Answer (score 0):

What about this? Also check `help labels`.

**Code:**

```
### plot with values as labels at datapoints
reset session

$Data <<EOD
2019-08-28,384.00
2019-08-29,394.00
2019-08-30,354.00
2019-08-31,384.00
2019-09-01,484.00
2019-09-02,324.00
2019-09-03,384.00
EOD

set datafile separator ","
set offsets 0.5,0.5,20,20

myLabel(n) = sprintf("%g",n)
plot $Data u 2:xtic(1) w lp pt 7 lc rgb "blue" title "MB used", \
     $Data u 0:2:(myLabel($2)) w labels offset 0,1.5 notitle
### end of code
```

**Result:**

[image]